# VB.NET AutoResetEvent

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am trying to learn more about event handling. I tried writing the code below but it doesn't seem to be working for some reason. What I am trying to do is navigating to a url, wait until its loaded and then run the msgbox.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
Private Shared event_1 As New AutoResetEvent(False)

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://google.com")
    AddHandler WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted, New WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(AddressOf wb)

    event_1.WaitOne()

    MsgBox("The page is finished loading ")

End Sub

Private Sub wb(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs)
    If e.Url.AbsolutePath <> TryCast(sender, WebBrowser).Url.AbsolutePath Then
        Return
    End If
   event_1.Set()
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted.aspx

Comment: You are blocking your UI thread, use the `DocumentedCompleted` Event that Microsoft designed to be used for that purpose. It does not fire until the page finishes loading.

Comment: I did check msdn WebBrowser.DocumentCompleted Event earlier when i was writing the code, but what i'm having difficulties with is making the program wait until the WebBrowser.DocumentCompleted is done then carry on with the rest. thats why i used AutoResetEvent, i was trying to make the program wait until .set() triggers and then carry on with the rest of the program. Without the AutoResetEvent the program will  work but it will do everything in one go (i.e. it will not wait until the pages is loaded) which cause a problem.

Comment: I don't know why @LaurenceMoroney deleted his answer - it's essentially correct - whatever you want to do after the document has loaded should be in the `DocumentCompleted` event handler, *not* in the button's `Click` event. Move the code there and delete the `AutoResetEvent`. Also, just for sanity's sake, you ought to attach the event handler *before* you call `Navigate`. It's technically a race at the moment.

Comment: Weird. I had edited it because I did the NavigationCompleted handler instead of DocumentCompleted. Undeleted now.

Comment: Yeah i believe the best thing to do is to move the rest of the code to DocumentCompleted event handler. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just catch the DocumentCompleted event on the WebBrowser1 object like this:

```
Private Sub webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, _
    ByVal e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) _
    Handles webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted

    MsgBox("THe page is loaded")

End Sub
```

See samples here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2

Answer (score 1):

When you issue the `event_1.WaitOne()`, the main thread is blocked. And that includes the WebBrowser. Therefore the `event_1.Set()` will never get executed.

However, you can achieve the same behavior with a different method. Not using event whatsoever.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Me.Enabled = False ' if you realy want to block the UI as well
    WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.google.com")

    Do
      Application.DoEvents()
    Loop Until WebBrowser1.ReadyState = WebBrowserReadyState.Complete

    MsgBox("The page is finished loading ")
    Me.Enabled = True ' re-enable the UI
End Sub
```